# Importing a specific rows from excel into sas

Tags: excel, date, sas

I have an excel sheet with three columns: Date, FMV% and Deal# :

```
    date          FMV%     Deal#
    11/17/2015    0.97     1601
    11/30/2015    0.95     1601
    12/18/2015    0.95     1602
    12/31/2015    0.97     1602
    1/18/2016     0.97     1602
    1/31/2016     0.95     1602
```

I need to use the FMV% from that excel file and create a new column in SAS, multiplying it with the current principal every month.

11/30/2015 is the first month end. I need to get the FMV% every time a loan is committed. The date may be any date of that month, and I need to get the FMV% Corresponding to that date.

There will be any date in a month and the month end date for the FMV% value. At MonthEnd1 we will have the columns for FMV as:

- `FMV_DOC%`
- `FMV_DOC_AMT`
- `DMV_DOC_ADJ`
- `FMV_DOC_ADI_AMT`
- `FMV_ME1%`
- `FMV_ME1_AMT`
- `FMV_ME1_ADJ`
- `FMV_ME1_ADI_AMT`

In the MonthEnd2, 4 columns will be added as follows:

- `FMV_ME2%`
- `FMV_ME2_AMT`
- `FMV_ME2_ADJ`
- `FMV_ME2_ADI_AMT`

In the next MonthEnd, 4 more columns will be added with the corresponding value of FMV% from that excel file and it goes on.

In the example,

- `11/30/2015` is `MonthEnd0`
- `12/31/2015` is `MonthEnd1`
- `01/31/2016` is `MonthEnd2`, and so on.

Also,

- `FMV_DOC_ADI_AMT = FMV_DOC_ADJ`
- `FMV_ME1_ADI_AMT = FMV_DOC_ADI_AMT-FMV_ME1_ADJ`
- `FMV_ME2_ADI_AMT = FMV_ME1_ADI_AMT-FMV_ME2_ADJ`,  and so on.

How can I direct SAS to get the correct FMV% every month whenever the deal happened and at the MonthEnd?

The path of the excel file is `C:\users\b787893\Desktop\FMV\FMV.xls`

Comment: I did quite a bit of reformatting to clarify your question, but too many things remain unclear in your first 3 paragraphs... What's "current principal"? And is this Excel file your only source of data? Otherwise, where do all other columns come from, apart from those which you define at the bottom?